# What is the correct way to push in vector of pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Previously I had this:

```
vector<CThing>things;
void Add(const CThing & ins){ things.push_back(ins); }
```

Now I need to change the declaration because of slicing to:

```
vector<CThing*>things;
```

or

```
vector<unique_ptr<CThing>>;
```

But I am not sure how to implement the Add function...

I tried:

```
things.push_back(*ins);
```

or

```
things.emplace_back(ins)
```

Comment: Do you understand how to apply the address of operator to get a pointer to an object? If not, then don't bother with `unique_ptr` and move semantics yet.

Comment: If you want the vector to take ownership, `std::unique_ptr<CThing>` is the way to go. Your function should then take a already made `std::unique_ptr<CThing>` as argument.

Comment: @DeiDei Ok, I won't, but I still don't know how to do that, the duplicate question got an answer that I should do "things.push_back(&ins); ". Am I right? But this gives me an error: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const CThing' to 'const value_type'

Comment: You need to learn to produce [mcve]s.